# drop a single column from a pandas DataFrame index without reset_index()

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with a very large DataFrame with many index columns and I wish to convert a few columns from the index to regular columns.

Below is a simplified example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col_a': [1,2,3],
        'col_b': [4,5,6],
        'index_1': ['a','b','c'],
        'index_2': ['f','g','h'],
        'index_to_column': [True,False,False],
    },
).set_index(['index_1', 'index_2', 'index_to_column'])
```

In the example above I would like `index_to_column` to be dropped from the index and become a normal column

Is it possible to perform this operation without calling `df.reset_index().set_index(['index_1', 'index_2'])` as when dealing with very large numbers of columns and multiple columns to drop I find it gets confusing very quickly.

Comment: check your input, it gives `KeyError: "None of ['index_to_convert'] are in the columns"`

Comment: *"but it is not a MultiIndex df"* — Eh? Yes it is, not that it changes the question. `isinstance(df.index, pd.MultiIndex)` → `True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify a level(s) to be reset:

```
df.reset_index(2)
```

---

```
                index_to_column  col_a  col_b
index_1 index_2                               
a       f                   True      1      4
b       g                  False      2      5
c       h                  False      3      6
```

---

To reset multiple selective indices pass a list of levels positions to [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) like:

```
df.reset_index(level=[0, 2])
```

or a list of level names:

```
df.reset_index(level=['index_to_column', 'index_1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution: Use `.reset_index` but for clarity specify the index by name:

```py
print(df.reset_index(level="index_to_column"))
```

Prints:

```
                 index_to_column  col_a  col_b
index_1 index_2                               
a       f                   True      1      4
b       g                  False      2      5
c       h                  False      3      6
```